# solve $a_n=a_{n-1}^2-\lambda, a_0=\beta$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

i was solving problems about sequences from a book (it is not english).here is the problem.

suppose that $a_n=a_{n-1}^2-2, a_0=3$ n then find

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  (\prod_{n=0}^{N-1} a_n)^{\frac{1}{2N} }$$

in teh offcial solution it says , suppose $\alpha=\frac{3+ \sqrt{5} }{2}$ then $a_0=\alpha+{\alpha}^{-1}$ then using induction one can obtain:

$$a_n={\alpha}^{2^{n}}+{\alpha}^{-(2^{n})}$$ so it is pretty easy to se the $limit$ is $\alpha$.

the thing is , the solution is not clear for me, how we should find $\alpha$?
or how we should solve such recurrence equation?
thanks.

Comment: The fact that if $x=\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ then $\alpha^2+\alpha^{-2}=x^2-2$, is algebraic and works for every $\alpha\ne0$. So, once the idea to use this trick arises, all that is left to do is to find $\alpha$ such that $a_0=\alpha+\alpha^{-1}$ and the proof is over. Is this your question?

Comment: For example, to solve $a_n=a_{n-1}^2-2$, $a_0=7$, one would solve $\alpha+{\alpha}^{-1}=7$, yielding $\alpha=\frac{7+\sqrt{45}}2$, *et voilà!*

Comment: well i think some how now i see what is your point, but i mean in such recurrence equations is there any general solution , let say i change the equation to $a_n=a_{n-1}^3-2$ , then what should i do to find the general solution?

Comment: Please do not modify your post after the first version is studied in comments. If you have another problem, post it as another question.

Comment: @did , i am sorry . so i guess your first comment make it more clear now , but still why such form ? is not there any other way?!

Comment: There is no general method so solve such recurrence equations.  If you have any value besides $-2$ and $0$ in there, then there is no such simple solution as this.  Another way to do this particular one is to use the double-angle formula for cosines.

Comment: @Gedgar do you know any paper about such recurrence equations?

Comment: See papers on "Mandelbrot set".